# Is there any use of favicon.ico for mobile websites?

Tags: android, html, windows-phone-7, mobile-safari, mobile-website

Is there any use of **favicon.ico** for mobile websites? will it be shown in browser address bar and tabs in mobile websites

We use **apple icons** `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>` in mobile websites. what about Android, Blackberry and Windows 7 phone? Is favicon.ico useful for other mobile phones other then iOS mobiles

Comment: I've added an asnwer you may be interested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Here is my study about icons:*

Considering the tag: `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="IMAGE-NAME" />`

**Considering the sizes:**

`57x57px` default size

`72x72px` iPad size

`114x114px` Retina / Opera

**Images:**

`'apple-touch-icon.png'` - at iOS, in this image will applied the 'Gloss' effect. On other OS'es, nothing happens.

`'apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png'` - This image will not receive any effect

**Here is the following tests on OS':**

`BlackBerry v6.0 or higher` - Only works `'apple-touch-icon'`

`BlackBerry v5.9 or lower` - Not supported

`Android 2.2 or higher` - Works both versions

`Android 2.1 or lower` - Only works `'apple-touch-icon-precomposed'`

`iOS 4.1 or lower` - Works both versions

`iOS 4.2 or higher`  - Works both versions and accept size attributes (and so, sizes different from `57x57px`)

`Nokia's (probably S60 5th FP1 and higher, not fully confirmed)` - Some accept `'apple-touch-icon'`

`OperaMini (SpeedDial Shortcut)` - Works both versions BUT must have at LEAST `114x114px` (speed dial normally is `200x200px` if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

I can see tiny favicon in the browser address bar on my Android phone. I'm not sure how useful it is :) but it is there..

*UPDATE*

As far as I can see favicon is not displayed if I add a bookmark on the homescreen (at least not in HTC Sense)

And bookmarks in the browser itself are just tiny page screenshots, so favicons not used there as well.

Don't think they are useful at all on an Android device.

Comment: This seems to depend on the browser. For example, favicons are not displayed in the address bar but they are displayed in the Bookmarks menu in Opera Mobile on my G2.

Answer (score 1):

I add favicon to all mobile sites for 3 reasons:

1. It doesn't hurt
2. Looks good when browsing via PC :)
3. Some browsers look for it, so why would you return 404 and possibly use more bandwidth instead of sending a tiny favicon?

Answer (score 0):

if you add a book mark to your home screen it will use the favicon as the launcher icon.